# Add data using angular js and spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring

I'm new to Angular js and spring boot
i need to submit data via form i cant find how to add data to database
 this is html file :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Accueil</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body >
<div class="container">
<div ng-app="app">
<div  ng-controller="MainController as main">

        <h1>{{main.title}}</h1>

    <div >
<table >
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>nom</td>
<td>prenom</td>
<td>cin</td>
 <td>date naissance</td>
 <td>nationalite</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>



</tr>
<tr data-ng-repeat="a in etudiants"> 

<td>{{a.id}}</td>
<td>{{a.nom}}</td>
<td>{{a.prenom}}</td>
<td>{{a.cint}}</td>
<td>{{a.date_naissi}}</td>
<td>{{a.nat}}</td>
<td><a ng-click="editUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">edit</a></td>
 <td><a ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">delete</a></td>



</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div></div>

<br>
<div ng-app="appajout">
<div ng-controller="contAjout">

 <form ng-submit="submit()" role="form">
<input ng-model="nom"  type="text" name="nom"></input>
<input ng-model="prenom" type="text" name="prenom" ></input>
<input ng-model="cint" type="text" name="cint"></input>
<input ng-model="nat" type="text" name="nat"></input>
<input ng-model="dateNaissi" type="text" name="dateNaissi"></input>
<input class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()" type="submit" value="Submit">
<!-- <button ng-click="save()">ajouter</button> -->
</form>

</div> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

js file :

```
/*____________________________________test________________________________*/
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').controller("MainController", function($scope,$http){

     var vm = this;
      vm.title = 'Liste des etudiants';
     $scope.etudiants=[];

             $http.get("/etudiant/listeEtudiant").success(function(data)
                        {
                             $scope.etudiants = data;


                        });

});
/*____________________________________Ajout________________________________*/
var app=angular.module('appajout', []);
//angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('contAjout', function($scope,$http){

     $scope.nom=null; 
     $scope.prenom=null; 
     $scope.cint=null; 
     $scope.nat=null;
     $scope.dateNaissi=null;

     $scope.submit = function submit() {

           $http.post("/etudiant/ajouter?nom="+$scope.nom+
                "&prenom="+$scope.prenom+
                "&cint="+$scope.cint+
                "&nat="+$scope.nat+
                "&dateNaissi="+$scope.dateNaissi
         )
            .success(function(data, status, headers) {
            alert("Task added");

              });

         };

});
```

i want to know what is problem in the code!

this is my controller :

```
  @Autowired 
    private EtudiantRepository etudiantRepository;
//  @Secured(value="ROLE_ADMIN")
    @RequestMapping(value="/etudiant/ajouter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Etudiant ajout(Etudiant e)
            {
        return etudiantRepository.save(e);
            }
```

Comment: What is the error? Where is your controller code?

Comment: i m not able to add data to database whene i click to save button!

Comment: That is not "the error", that is the symptom.   Why doesn't it add data to the database? Does your "save" function run? Does the `$http` call run? Does the network tab show the `$http` call working properly?

Comment: yes save function  run properly and $http run too!!!

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, the ng-click="save()" does not match the function $scope.submit. You need to change it to

```
<button ng-click="submit()">ajouter</button>
```

Comment: If you don't post your entire code no one can help you. Also if you're using Chrome open the "inspect" tools and check "console" and "network" to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have multiple angular modules defined in the same html. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

> only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML
>   document

Delete the first ng-app and it will work. Also you have

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" role="form">
```

and

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

This will POST twice on each click. And it will refresh the entire page which is something you don't want to do in modern single page web apps. You could remove the form entirely, remove the input type button entirely and just keep the

```
<button ng-click="submit()">ajouter</button>
```